# “extra characters after command” in the sed command a

Tags: shell-script, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
SVG=$1
CSV=$2

for p in "$CSV"; do
LINEA=$(cut -d',' -f1 $p | sed '1d')
LINEB=$(cut -d',' -f2 $p | sed '1d')
if grep -iq "$LINEA" "$SVG"; then
sed '/g id=\"..\"/a style=\"fill:'"$LINEB"';\"' $SVG > temp.svg
else
echo "ERROR"
fi
done
```

When I execute this script with two files I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 66: extra characters after command
```

Answer (score 3):

*some* `sed`s will tolerate a `[aic]` command which is not immediately followed by a backslash-escaped newline and then all of the relevant *`text`* like:

```
sed '/address/atext'
```

...and even for those that *do* tolerate it without the escaped newline, what they might do with leading white-space is implementation-specific as well, so...

```
sed '/address/a text'
```

...may come out the same as...

```
sed '/address/atext'
```

...the portable and [standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) way to write any of those is...

```
sed '/address/a\
text and embedded newline\
more appended text
/next command/...'
```

Comment: Using the same sed command in a shell script, with GNU sed v2.05 on Debian 1.1, I receive the error, `sed: Extra characters after command`, but on GNU sed 4.7 on Debian 9, I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Order of **sed** flags may output error `extra characters after command`

This is wrong:

```
sed -i fileName -r 's/a/b/g'
```

Corrected:

```
sed -r 's/a/b/g' -i fileName
```

Comment: This is correct information, but not relevant to the code shown in the current question.